# Do tables always appear at the end of elsarticle class?

Tags: tables, elsarticle

I'm using `\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}`, my tables which I would like to appear in the middle of text goes to the very end page of my article, this is really not what I looking for as I want to give some explanation and analyze the result. What should I do, is it due to `elsarticle` class or what? Is there anyway to fix it if so.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Do the journal editors want to get a camera ready pdf? I guess not. Elsevier is typesetting the article for you, you just feed them your research.

Comment: And drop the overleaf tag. Nothing to do with a third party website.

Comment: Ok, so you think that's not an issue, thanks.

Comment: The `elsarticle` document class is built on the more basic `article` document class and doesn't contain code that would *ipso facto* force all floats to be output at the very end of the document. Thus, it's more likely that there's something about one or more of the `table` environments that's causing the problem. Please tell us more about the specifics of the document's `table` environments. E.g., do you load them with any particular positioning specifiers (e.g., `h`, `t`, `b`, `p`)? How tall are they? Does anything happen if you change, say, `\begin{table}` to `\begin{table}[htbp]`?

Comment: Hey @Mico, it actually worked when I used `\begin{table}[htbp]`, awesome, thank you! this is the same table you[ suggested here] ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537846/how-to-fix-this-table-in-latex/537867?noredirect=1#comment1358993_537867) with 20 rows.

Comment: @ELLA - So glad my suggestion worked out. In case you're interested in learning more about how LaTeX places "float" environments such as `table` and `figure`, I highly recommend reading the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001) and, in particular, [Frank Mittelbach's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5001).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Mico, you are so much helpful :). I sure will read it as I'm a beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP's question was answered in the comments section.